# Would some with sufficient rep please make a 'databasedotcom' tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

This [set of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=databasedotcom) about the databasedotcom (salesforce) Ruby gem deserve to be tagged [databasedotcom](/questions/tagged/databasedotcom) but I do not have the rep to make a new tag. Can someone please create this tag so it can be used for databasedotcom gem-related questions?

Comment: Ick.  Someone really named their software thingy "databasedotcom?"  How about [databasedotcom-gem]?  I don't want this tag to be an excuse for others to make tags like [myfavoritesitedotcom].

Comment: @bill How about Robert's suggestion in the comment above?

Comment: Humm... hadn't thought about the [mysupercoolframeworkdotcom] problem... sorry for the hasty tagging.

Comment: @Bart Yep, I agree.  The tag would be better with the `-gem` suffix.  I went ahead and changed them all to that.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Thanks gents! I agree completely that databasedotcom is a lame name and databasedotcom-gem is a better tag name than I asked for. Thanks again!